# Symfony2/Doctrine - Query join com tres entidades diferentes

Tags: doctrine-2, symfony-2

Da maneira abaixo funciona corretamente:

```
$qb->select('partial t.{id,nsu,status,message}, partial u.{id,shortName,email} as user')
   ->from('GatewayBundle:Transaction', 't')
   ->join('GatewayBundle:User', 'u')
   ->where('u.id = t.user');
```

Quando adiciono outro `join`, resulta num **erro** de sintaxe:

> ERRO - [Syntax Error] line 0, col 461: Error:Expected Literal, got 'JOIN' **500** Internal Server Error - QueryException

```
$qb->select('partial t.{id,nsu,status,message}, partial u.{id,shortName,email} as user, partial p.{id} as partner')
   ->from('GatewayBundle:Transaction', 't')
   ->join('GatewayBundle:User', 'u')
   ->join('GatewayBundle:Partner', 'p')
   ->where('u.id = t.user')
   ->andWhere('p.id = t.partner');
```

Qual a sintaxe correta para esse tipo de consulta?

Answer (score 1):

Funcionou desta maneira:

```
$qb
    ->select('
        t.id, t.nsu, t.status, t.message, 
        u.id as u_id, u.shortName as u_shortName , u.email as u_email, 
        p.id as p_id, p.name as p_name')
    ->from('PaylevenGatewayBundle:Transaction', 't')
    ->join('t.user', 'u')
    ->join('t.partner', 'p');
```

Comment: Se deu certo, não esqueça de validar sua própria resposta :)